# How to Dynamically populate listview elements in android

Tags: android, listview, dynamic-programming

I have 2 activities both of them has list views in it.The first list view is already populated with some elements.For example the list view in activity 1 has semesters like sem-1,sem-2 so on etc.Now what i want to achieve is when i click on sem-1 the respective subjects gets populated in the list view of 2nd activity with all on click classes etc...I tried it using putextra as shown in the below code but it is not loading any list view at all in the second activity.
The code i had used.

Activity-1

```
 case 1:
              i = new Intent(Syllabus.this, Subjects.class);
              i.putExtra("sem", "cse11");
              startActivity(i);
```

Activity-2

```
if(getIntent().getStringExtra("sem")=="cse11") {
 // Defined Array values to show in ListView
        String[] values = new String[]{"ENGLISH-I",
                "MATHEMATICS-I",
                "PHYSICS-I",
                "MATHEMATICAL METHODS",
                "COMPUTER PROGRAMMING THROUGH C",
                "ENGINEERING DRAWING",
                "ENGINEERING & IT WORKSHOP",
                "ENGINEERING PHYSICS LAB",
                "COMPUTER PROGRAMMING THROUGH C LAB"
        };
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to compare strings with `==`, there is the error. Avoid it in that case. Use [`.equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) instead.

Here's the code for the second activity, try it:

```
if(getIntent().getStringExtra("sem").equals("cse11")) {
 // Defined Array values to show in ListView
        String[] values = new String[]{"ENGLISH-I",
                "MATHEMATICS-I",
                "PHYSICS-I",
                "MATHEMATICAL METHODS",
                "COMPUTER PROGRAMMING THROUGH C",
                "ENGINEERING DRAWING",
                "ENGINEERING & IT WORKSHOP",
                "ENGINEERING PHYSICS LAB",
                "COMPUTER PROGRAMMING THROUGH C LAB"
        };
}
```